# Remove unwanted text from column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I dont know how to do this. On my table I have descriptions mixed with description code. I need to remove the code description, just want the description. The description is just the first part without the acronym (capital letters at the end). I use SQL Server 2012

Example:

```
ColumnDescription
Chemistry Q
education E
psychology P
Sociology SOC
Documentation DOC
communication COM
Political Science CP
Pharmacy and Toxicology FT
Engineering Education (General) ING-G
```

Comment: How do you identify the `description code`?

Comment: Uppsss sorry...Edited

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Are you saying that you wish to extract (for example) 'Sociology' instead of 'Sociology SOC', or that you want to extract the 'SOC' part?

Comment: Want to remove SOC, the description has to be Sociology, for example, sorry for the misunderstood.

Comment: I have to remove all capital letter from back to end and stop when not find an uppercase, but dont know how to do it.

Comment: You should definitely rethink your data model. Now you have two values of different domains within one column. Your question proves that violating first normal form is not a good idea. There probably will exist some hack to get the wanted information from your column, but it'll be a better idea to add a column to the table containing the abbreviation and keep the original column for the description. Getting the originally stored value is easy (just concatenate).

Comment: Oh, and you could also try to find the last blank and skip from there. I guess that's easier than distinguishing between upper and lower case letters

Comment: Yes I know, it´s not my data model, I just want to remodel the DB, so I have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to simply strip the code that is at the end of each string, a way to do this is to identify the last space character in the string and then use `SUBSTRING` to extract everything before that character:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(ColumnDescription, 0, LEN(ColumnDescription) - CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(ColumnDescription)) + 1) AS ColumnDescription
  FROM  Table
```

Note that I do not know what your table is called, so I called it `Table`.

This effectively reverses the column text (using `REVERSE`), finds the first occurrence of a space character (using `CHARINDEX`) and then subtracts this from the length of the text (using `LEN`).
Then a simple `SUBSTRING` is used to extract the left-most portion of the text, resulting in the output of:

```
ColumnDescription
-----------------
Chemistry
education
psychology
Sociology
Documentation
communication
Political Science
Pharmacy and Toxicology
Engineering Education (General)
```

Comment: However, it does not do what OP originally wanted: remove/extract the part that contains only uppercase letters from the right side. Consider that the last desc-code would be `ING G`(incl. space).

Comment: Yes u are right, but fortunatelly all the description I have doesnt have space between code, all code is together, in some cases separated with a -. Thanks for you tip!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data I would guess that your problem *could* be simplified to:

> Split the string at the last space character in the string

In which case:

```
DECLARE @your_table table (
   ColumnDescription varchar(100)
);

INSERT INTO @your_table (ColumnDescription)
  VALUES ('Chemistry Q')
       , ('education E')
       , ('psychology P')
       , ('Sociology SOC')
       , ('Documentation DOC')
       , ('communication COM')
       , ('Political Science CP')
       , ('Pharmacy and Toxicology FT')
       , ('Engineering Education (General) ING-G');

SELECT *
     , SubString(ColumnDescription, number_of_characters - last_space + 2, 100) As last_part
     , SubString(ColumnDescription, 0, number_of_characters - last_space + 2) As first_part
FROM   (
        SELECT ColumnDescription
             , Len(ColumnDescription) As number_of_characters
             , Reverse(ColumnDescription) As reversed
             , CharIndex(' ', Reverse(ColumnDescription)) As last_space
        FROM   @your_table
       ) As x;
```